# SharePoint online file sync to Azure blob storage with logic app getting error for .mp4 files

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-apps

I have created an Azure Logic app that replicates the file structure in Azure blob storage. It works fine until I add a folder and files under the folder in SharePoint. When I try to read the contents through "Get file content", I get the error "BadRequest" and in the output Body, I get

status : 400
message : Route did not match\r\nclientRequestID

Is this error because of the folder path or maybe because of audio files in the folder?

Second issue - How can recursive functionality be achieved in the logic app, so that if its folder is within the folder then its read all the files and store them in the same hierarchy in the blob container?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving this because of the folder path, I assume you are trying to copy the blob according to its path and hence you receive that error.

> Second issue - How can recursive functionality be achieved in the logic app, so that if its folder is within the folder then its read all the files and store them in the same hierarchy in the blob container?

you can use for-each loop in order to list all the files which are present inside subfolders too. Below is my logic app where I'm trying to create folders according to the hierarchical structure present in SharePoint.

[image]

Below is the Expression in `Extracting folder excluding file name to create sub folders in blob storage`

```
slice(outputs('Path_of_subfolder'),0,lastIndexOf(outputs('Path_of_subfolder'),'/'))
```

Below is the Expression in `Path of subfolder`

```
@{items('For_each_3')?['{FullPath}']}
```

Comment: Thanks Swetha, The app has been deployed on production and working fine.